# spray client sometimes throws Corrupt data (CRC32 checksum error)

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-client

I wrote my client code as

```
 val pipeGzipGet: HttpRequest => Future[String] = (
    addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip ")
      ~> sendReceive
      ~> logByteArray
      ~> decode(Gzip)
      ~> unmarashal[String]
  )
```

It works fine most times , but will sometimes throw a

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: Corrupt data (CRC32 checksum error)
        at spray.httpx.encoding.GzipDecompressor.fail$1(Gzip.scala:91) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at spray.httpx.encoding.GzipDecompressor.readTrailer$1(Gzip.scala:117) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at spray.httpx.encoding.GzipDecompressor.decomp(Gzip.scala:131) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at spray.httpx.encoding.GzipDecompressor.decompress(Gzip.scala:85) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at spray.httpx.encoding.Decompressor.decompress(Decoder.scala:41) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at spray.httpx.encoding.Decoder$class.decode(Decoder.scala:28) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at spray.httpx.encoding.Gzip.decode(Gzip.scala:23) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at spray.httpx.ResponseTransformation$$anonfun$decode$1.apply(ResponseTransformation.scala:28) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at spray.httpx.ResponseTransformation$$anonfun$decode$1.apply(ResponseTransformation.scala:28) ~[io.spray.spray-httpx-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
```

I also found some message may related to this from akka log

```
[akka://application/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/14] Message [akka.io.Tcp$Write] from Actor[akka://application/user/IO-HTTP/group-0/14#592690058] to Actor[akka://application/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/14#-1139525337] was not delivered. [10] dead letters encountered, no more dead letters will be logged. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'
```

Then I log the response with

```
val logByteArray = (r: HttpResponse) => {
      val bytes = r.entity.as[Array[Byte]]
      import java.util.Date
      import java.io._
      import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
      val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH_mm_ss_SSS" + idSeq.incrementAndGet)
      val fout = new FileOutputStream(s"${sys.env("HOME")}/dump-${sdf.format(new Date)}")
      fout.write(bytes.right.get)
      fout.flush()
      fout.close()
    r
  }
```

I use `gzip -t` to test that file. It says

> invalid compressed data--crc error

Seems response is corrupt.

> But I tried with the request with an chrome plugin, it never fail.

Is it possible to avoid the exception ?

Comment: It looks like the incoming data was corrupted (or there's a bug with the decompression routine in spray) but we cannot know without a reproduction. If the errors happen often enough could you use wireshark to acquire a network capture that contains the problem and post it on the mailing list?

Comment: This not happens every time even with the same request.And When I disable the gzip , the request is always fine.  Anyway , I will try to dump the bytes and post it.

Comment: @jrudolph I found the response are splited into two response(possibly chunk response, i guess). Does spray worked with chunked gzip http response?

Comment: "Then when I call a single request, it produces two response." -  In which way does it produce two responses? How do you use `logByteArray`?

Comment: @jrudolph There is only one request, that's my falut.

Comment: @jrudolph The incoming data seems corrupted, please make an answer.